# Aggregate elements returned from filetring processor in spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

My use case starts by reading PK from database, a filtering processor check if the id is already processed, if not a second processor will get the other columns using the id from db.

I'am trying to reduce the roundtrip with database, is it possible to aggregate the ids so i can execute batch read ?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a database table (eg. PROCESSED) to store the ids that have already been processed, or use a status column on the existing table that you're reading.  Your reader can use something similar to "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PROCESSED p WHERE p.ID = x.ID)" to avoid selecting already processed items.

For this solution you need to consider how job restarts behave and make sure to call `saveState(false)` since you're maintaining the state of already processed items yourself.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#process-indicator

Comment: The problem is that i don't have any right to write or make changes on input database, so i'm thinking about using third party persistent store(eg: persistent hashmap) and store processing state for every row processed.